# Build 32 bit OpenCV on a 64 bit platform

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, compilation, 32bit-64bit, elf

I am trying to run a pre-compiled program on my Ubuntu 64 bit system:

```
$  ./segmentObjs 
./segmentObjs: error while loading shared libraries: 
  libopencv_core.so.2.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I suspect this means that the program is looking for a 32 bit version of the `libopencv_core`library, but can only find a 64 bit version.

Is it possible to install a 32 bit version of OpenCV alongside my current version, and get this binary to use that one instead of the present installation? The downloads section of OpenCV only seems to offer one choice, and when I attempted to build version 2.3 of OpenCV I couldn't find any options to build a 32 bit version in 'cmake-gui'.

Is what I am trying to do impossible or am I just attempting it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done but you have to install ia32-libs plus all the dependencies of opencv in 32bit.

Comment: Ouch. I think it might be easier to install a 32-bit Ubuntu Virtual Machine and do it all on there. At least that's what I'm doing for the time being!

Comment: Probably it's the best idea. The other way can be troublesome.